# How to force an error in Python when calling a function without ()

Tags: python

An bug that has bedeviled me a number of times is calling a function without (), and assuming that it has run when it hasn't.  Here's a simple scenario:

```
class testDoubling:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def update(self):
        self.x *= 2
```

Now in my code I initialize:

```
myval = testDoubling( 2 )
```

Then later in my code I call the following expecting it to double the stored parameter:

```
myval.update
```

Python happily runs without complaining, but does not update myval.x.  It only updates myval.x when I call it with the parentheses:

```
myval.update()
```

This lurking bug in my code has caused me a good many lost hours.  Surely there is some way either my IDE or python itself can warn me, or an error can be forced when forgetting the ()?

Comment: There's no such thing as a function call without `()`. Further, a function call is an expression, just like a reference to a function is an expression. It's not clear why your IDE would know that you intended to call the function.

Comment: One reason you won't see this feature is because there are perfectly valid reasons for passing function objects around:  `map(sum, my_list)` and `map(itemgetter(1), my_list)` are both totally valid.  This is the kind of mistake that becomes much easier to spot with experience.

Comment: You just have to learn to catch it. Python has reasons for doing things this way. What language did you come from where calling functions without parenthesis was "normal"?

Comment: Actually I came from Matlab which calls functions even without parentheses.  I've been working at Python, but it takes a while ...

Answer (score 1):

In short you can't.

With your code this line

```
myval.update
```

It should return function object itself without executing so it is not an error and your IDE can not do anything about it

Don't forget "()"s they are important.

Here your code...

```
In [1]: class testDoubling:
   ...:     def __init__(self, x):
   ...:         self.x = x
   ...:     def update(self):
   ...:         self.x *= 2    
In [2]: myval = testDoubling( 2 )
In [3]: myval.update
Out[3]: <bound method testDoubling.update of <__main__.testDoubling object at 0x103766048>>    
In [4]: myval.x
Out[4]: 2
```

Comment: s/function body/function object/

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Even someone didn't like my answer :)

Comment: Yes it is not an error, but the IDE could warn me that I have a line that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions (and methods) are objects too... `myval.update` is a perfectly valid Python expression that lookups the name "update" on object `myval`. This name is resolved as being the `update` function of class `testDoubling`, wrapped into a `method` object (so you don't have to explicitly pass `myval` as argument when calling it), and, well, since you're not doing anything with it, it's then discarded, but you could want to store it somewhere for future use, pass it to another function as callback etc etc etc.

IOW it's just another object and there are a lot of use case for passing functions or methods around. OR you could actually just call it, which is done by applying the call operator `()`.  FWIW, your question's title is technically wrong - you can NOT "call a function without ()" since "()" IS the call operator.

Note that functions are not the only callable objects either - we have already mentionned methods (actually what `myval.update` evals too), but there are also classes (yes, Python classes are objects too - everything in Python is an object), and you can write your own callable types too.

TL;DR: referencing a function or method without calling it is perfectly legal, legitimate and actually a very common idiom, neither Python nor your IDE have any reason to consider this an error, and it's your duty as a programmer to make sure you apply the call operator when you want to call a function.

Comment: Yes you are right.  However, forgetting to add `()` seems like an easy mistake to make.  Add to that, if I write `myval.update` on its own it does nothing, so why doesn't the IDE at least warn me that I have a line that is doing nothing?

Comment: @DanielMorris As I mentionned above, referencing a function or method is not only legal (it's not a syntax error) but also a very common idiom (when you want to pass the function or method to another function or store it for later use). Also the evaluation of the expression `myval.update`  COULD have side effects   (via the descriptor protocol) so neither the compiler (which only see it as an attribute lookup) nor runtime (which doesn't know beforehand what this expression will yield) can assume it's a no-op.

Comment: wrt/ "forgetting to add ()" being "an easy mistake", once you understand that the `obj.method()` expression is interpreted as an attribute lookup (`obj.method`) followed by a call (`()`), there's no reason you should forgot the call.

Comment: Ah, so if an attribute lookup like `myval.update` could have side effects, then yes, there is probably nothing the IDE can do as the line might do something.  Thanks for the explanation!